# Installation in a new environement: conda install or pip install?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda, tensorflow-datasets

I recently installed tensorflow 2.0 by creating a new environment called "tensorflow". I usually activate that environment before doing any work (e.g., calling jupyter notebook) by typing "`conda activate tensorflow`" in Anaconda prompt.

Sorry i am a beginner in this.  it happens that i need to install new package there called `tensorflow_datasets` . I know that i can do `pip install tensorflow_datasets` but i am concerned that using `pip` under this tensorflow conda environment may mess up my tensorflow installation like it did in the past. Can you please advise me on how i should do the installation? would you recommend `conda install tensorflow_datasets`?

More generally, once we create a new environment how can we install new packages there?

Many Thanks

Comment: If you installed tensorflow with conda, I'd recommend you to stick with conda: `conda install -n tensorflow tensorflow-datasets`. If you installed tensorflow with pip, it's arguably best to stick with pip.
`More generally, once we create a new environment how can we install new packages there?` - you activate it with `conda activate <env-name>` then use `pip install <pkg-name>` or `conda install pkg-name>`. Consistency is a good way to avoid troubles.

Comment: @cell  thanks so much. Your answer is super clear and helps me a lot

Comment: _More generally, once we create a new environment how can we install new packages there?_ I'll add that the ideal/best workflow is to specify all the packages you need when the environment is created, and not modify anything after that.

Comment: I see what you mean that's why i am very careful/selective when adding new packages in the newly created environment. However, it is very hard to anticipate all packages you may need in the future, it would say adding new packages is almost inevitable